# Disable NSLog for CocoaPods

Tags: objective-c, logging, macros, cocoapods

I am using several [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org) in my project. Some of them are outputting strings to the console via `NSLog()`.

**How can I disable all logging from CocoaPods?**

Also, is there a way to do so while still keeping all of my `NSLog`s enabled?

**Note:** it seems like [this feature](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/833) may resolve the issue, but are there alternatives I can use meanwhile?

**Update:** looks like this [feature was requested](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1630).

Comment: That won't be possible without hacking the code, however it should only mean editing a single header file per pod and defining `NSLog` to do nothing with a `#define`.

Comment: did u find any solution? @trojanfoe what do u mean by single header file? where is that?  and what about when we update a pod?  we need to redefine it.